# JSON documentation

Tags: javascript, json, couchdb

Is there a good tool for writing JSON specifications?

I'm looking to improve my internal team's documentation capabilities, and at the same time generation validators (which could be throw into CouchDB view).

Comment: I love this question. How great would it be to automate the testing of JSON objects returned from web controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://json-schema.org/

Also see :

[cerny.js](http://www.cerny-online.com/cerny.js/documentation/guides/schema) (JavaScript)
[JSONTools](http://jsontools.berlios.de/) (Java)

Comment: Oh, thank you; I was about to launch Antlr and make my own. This helps me nicely.

Comment: How about the documentation part? Is there something that produces nice schema documentation like oXygen XML does for XML?

Answer (score 2):

For the specification - i think [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/) has enough detail.

As for validation- you can't go past [JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com/).

Comment: I think he means "specifications" as in specifying valid formats of their own data structures. Like DTDs for XML schemas.

Comment: I think Math is asking for a tool to document or validate a data file or stream written in JSON (just like a DTD for an XML file), instead of the documentation for JSON itself.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - fair enough, in that case i don't know if one exists for JSON. @Sebastian Grignoli - JSONLint **can** validate either a file or a URL containing JSON.

Comment: *"i don't know if one exists for JSON"* Apparently so (see BGerrissen's answer), with SitePen behind it no less. Did not know that.

Comment: What I meant is that Math seems to be asking for a tool to define and validate the semantics of a file, instead of just the syntax.